# Can i add database table manually in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel

can i add database table in my Laravel application by creating model file and database in phpmyadmin manually? Will everything work fine? Thanks in advance.

Reason: My application is already hosted in the net and i don't know how to execute artisan commands in cpanel.

Comment: Yes it works, but its bad practice if you have multiple people working on that project

Comment: Yes you can, but read this first https://laravel.io/forum/02-01-2014-convince-me-of-the-advantages-of-l4-migrations

Comment: You can but that is not recommended. Can you please mention why can't you use migrations ?

Comment: you can do anything manually. there is no restriction about do with only command and everything works fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add database table to your laravel application using model and migrations. Please refer this : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/makemodel-also-creates-a-migration

Answer (score 0):

When a production environment doesn't allow artisan commands, you can pull the production database down, run the migrations locally, and then upload the database back.

Alternatively, you definitely can create your tables manually, but it's quite helpful to use migrations. They allow you to avoid manually adding tables in each environment -- less room for errors.

I'd recommend Laravel Valet to get things running locally if you have a Mac. It's quite simple to use. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet

Answer (score 0):

Yes
But when two or more programmers are writing together, they are not recommended.
GIT can help us better. Even in the database context

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add what columns you need in `Schema::create` method of the table and then add columns manually to database as migration create them and its works!

Answer (score 0):

if you import a table to your database ,for access it with a model first create related model ,for example if you import the car table ,create car model in terminal then in your model

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Car extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'car';
}
```

with  `protected $table = 'car'`   you attach the car table to car model , and you're done